# Create a list of RcppArmadillo matrices

Tags: r, rcpp

Deep inside an MCMC algorithm I need to multiply a user-provided list of matrices with a vector, i.e., the following piece of Rcpp and RcppArmadillo code is called multiple times per MCMC iteration:

```
List mat_vec1 (const List& Mats, const vec& y) {
    int n_list = Mats.size();
    Rcpp::List out(n_list);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_list; ++i) {
        out[i] = as<mat>(Mats[i]) * y;
    }
    return(out);
}
```

The user-provided list `Mats` remains fixed during the MCMC, vector `y` changes in each iteration. Efficiency is paramount and I'm trying to see if I can speed up the code by not having to convert the elements of `Mats` to arma::mat that many times (it needs to be done only once). I tried the following approach

```
List arma_Mats (const List& Mats) {
    int n_list = Mats.size();
    Rcpp::List res(n_list);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_list; ++i) {
        res[i] = as<mat>(Mats[i]);
    }
    return(res);
}
```

and then

```
List mat_vec2 (const List& Mats, const vec& y) {
    int n_list = Mats.size();
    Rcpp::List aMats = arma_Mats(Mats);
    Rcpp::List out(n_list);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_list; ++i) {
        out[i] = aMats[i] * y;
    }
    return(out);
}
```

but this does not seem to work. Any pointers of alternative/better solutions are much welcome.

Comment: `List` is an R (compatible Rcpp) type, which can store other R (compatibale Rcpp) types (and those for which we have converters) -- so you may have to `wrap()` your `arma::mat` first to help the compiler with a `SEXP`-compatible variable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So, if I understand correctly, `Rcpp::List` will convert the Armadillo matrices to plain Rcpp matrices. Is there any way to a create a `List` of Armadillo matrices, such then I can multiply them with an Armadillo vector **without** having to convert them back again?

Comment: Have a look at the Armadillo documentation;  `fields` classes may be what you want.  If you want to return data to R you need Rcpp types, or classes R and Rcpp knows about.  That includes Armadillo types via RcppArmadillo. Study some examples...

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I basically wrote the answer in the comment but it then occurred to me that we already provide a working example in the stub created by `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List rcpparma_bothproducts(const arma::colvec & x) {
    arma::mat op = x * x.t();
    double    ip = arma::as_scalar(x.t() * x);
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("outer")=op,
                              Rcpp::Named("inner")=ip);
}
```

This returns a list the outer product (a matrix) and the inner product (a scalar) of the given vector.

As for what is fast and what is not:  I recommend to not conjecture but rather *profile* and measure as much as you can.  My inclination would be to do more (standalone) C++ code in Armadillo and only return at the very end minimizing conversions.